# JTree and dropdown options on right clicking nodes

Tags: swing, popup, jtree

I'm trying to use the JTree and implement different drop downs for all the parent nodes and the children nodes.

Here's what I've done:

```
pmTree.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            try {
            if(evt.getButton() == evt.BUTTON1) {
            }
            else if (evt.getButton() == evt.BUTTON3) {
                TreePopup(evt);
                //pmTree.updateUI();
            }
            }catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });
```

and PopupCode:

```
public void TreePopup(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)  pmTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
    popup = new JPopupMenu();
    popup.setInvoker(pmTree);
    PopupHandler handler = new PopupHandler(pmTree, popup);
    if(node.getLevel() == 1)
    {
        popup.add(getMenuItem("Parent Node", handler));
    }
    else if(node.getLevel() == 2)
    {
        popup.add(getMenuItem("Child", handler));
     }
     }
```

and PopUpHandler:

```
public class PopupHandler extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {
JPopupMenu popup;
Point loc;

public PopupHandler(JTree tree, JPopupMenu popup) {
    //this.tree = NewJFrame.pmTree;
    this.popup = popup;
    tree.addMouseListener(ma);
}
```

and also the

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
```

for the Child or Parent node being clicked.

However, when I run the program, I get the SAME right click popups for both the child and parent node.

Sorry for the huge chunk of code. I've been stuck with it for 2 days and yet not successful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check the selected node:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)pmTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
```

to see if you have a "parent" or a "child" node. You should select the node at the mouse position first, otherwise it will not be the right node. Call

```
TreePath path = pmTree.getPathForLocation(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
if (path != null) {
    pmTree.setSelectionPath(path);
} else {
    return;
}
```

at the beginning of `treePopup`. (methods in Java should start with a lower case letter!)

Comment: no - in a well-behaved ui selection is unrelated to popup triggers

Comment: @kleopatra I disagree, right-clicking (popup trigger) usually selects. Look at Windows explorer, for example.

Comment: you are right - just checked. That's weird, I remember hefty debates with the Swing team forcing them into not selecting on right click. So at that time (cough ... a while ago) I guess win didn't select. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: hach ... deleted the older "cant work" - overlooked the "select first"

Answer (score 4):

Don't go as low-level as a MouseListener, instead use the api around componentPopupMenu. Doing so, the general approach is dynamically configure the componentPopup in the getPopupLocation method, some simple example snippet:

```
    JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    final Action action = new AbstractAction("empty") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };
    popup.add(action); 
    JTree tree = new JTree() {

        /** 
         * @inherited <p>
         */
        @Override
        public Point getPopupLocation(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e != null) {
               // here do your custom config, like f.i add/remove menu items based on context
               // this example simply changes the action name 
               TreePath path = getClosestPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
               action.putValue(Action.NAME, String.valueOf(path.getLastPathComponent()));
               return e.getPoint();
            }
            action.putValue(Action.NAME, "no mouse"); 
            return null;
        }

    };
    tree.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
```

Answer (score 1):

Awesome. I was successfully able to put the `setSelectionPath()` call inside the override of `getPopupLocaiton()`. I had been trying to do it inside the `ActionListener` of my `JMenuItem` to no avail.

```
public Point getPopupLocation( MouseEvent e ) {
    Point point = null;
    if( e != null ) {
        TreePath path = getClosestPathForLocation( e.getX(), e.getY() );
        setSelectionPath( path );
        point = e.getPoint();
    }
    return point;
}
```