# Changing nimbus JPopupmenu behaviour

Tags: java, swing, nimbus

I need help about nimbus behaviour for JTree and JPopupMenu. I am setting a right click menu to a JTree. If I left click to a node after open the right click menu with another node, clicked node becoming selected. but in nimbus look and feel, a second click needed for select another node. My code is below, you can try it with default look and feel with comment the nimbus part.

```
public class JTreeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        rootNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child1"));
        rootNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child2"));
        rootNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child3"));

        DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode);

        JTree tree = new JTree(model);
        tree.addMouseListener(new TreeMouseListener());

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(tree));

        jf.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class TreeMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
            JTree tree = (JTree) e.getSource();

            TreePath jClickedPath = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
            tree.setSelectionPath(jClickedPath);

            JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
            menu.add(new JMenuItem("menu1"));
            menu.show(tree,  e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [override getPopupLocation in the JTree](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8082241/714968), btw works for me on 1.st mouse event in Java 8 and Nimbus L&F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print out the pressed, released and clicked mouse events you will see that with the default L&F you get

```
// right click
tree: pressed
tree: released
tree: clicked
// click on node
tree: pressed
tree: released
tree: clicked
```

whereas with the Nimbus L&F you get

```
// right click
tree: pressed
tree: released
tree: clicked
// first click on node, the pressed event is not passed to the listener
tree: released
tree: clicked
// second click on node
tree: pressed
tree: released
tree: clicked
```

This is the desired behavior of Nimbus popups to consume the event on close. (see the explanation in the bug report [#JDK-6770445](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6770445))

You can change this behavior after setting the L&F.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
UIManager.put("PopupMenu.consumeEventOnClose", false);
```

**edit** Snippet to change the default behavior only for a specific `JTree`

```
// instruct the JTree not to close the popup
tree.putClientProperty("doNotCancelPopup",
    new JComboBox().getClientProperty("doNotCancelPopup"));

// create the popup menu not inside the listener
JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.add(new JMenuItem("menu1"));

// add the listener to the JTree
MouseListener popupListener = new PopupListener(popup);
tree.addMouseListener(popupListener);
```

Show and hide the popup programmatically

```
static class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter {

    JPopupMenu popup;

    PopupListener(JPopupMenu popupMenu) {
        popup = popupMenu;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        togglePopup(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        togglePopup(e);
    }

    private void togglePopup(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
            popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        } else if (popup.isVisible()) {
            popup.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is working but it is changing all popup's behaviour in my application. Is there a way to apply it to only one Jtree or one Popup.

Comment: @rdonuk As this is not a per-component property you either can change it before you display the `JTree` (which assumes no other popup could be displayed during the same time) or you try the snippet I add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions that you can try without changing nimbus:

**1.** Simulate second click using Robot class.

Add this to your MouseListener.

```
if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) && e.getSource() instanceof JTree) {
            Robot bot = null;
            try {
                bot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
}
```

**2.** Add [TreeSelectionLisitener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionListener.html) and same as in the first method use
    MouseListener to select the proper node with TreeSelectionListener.